# Ktor Kotlin Server obfuscation

Tags: kotlin, security, server, jwt, ktor

I made my first server with Ktor in Kotlin.
I want to know how secure is to host in a production server and how can I hide database password and other sensible information saved at "application.conf" file?

```
ktor {
deployment {
    port = 8080
    port = ${?PORT}
}

    application {
        modules = [ com.example.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
database {
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tests"
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}

email {
account = "ho"
password = "ho"
}
```

}

Comment: If this is just a simple project, you can use environment variables. For more professional situations, I've used Ansible with Spring, but not with Ktor -- not sure how it would work.

Comment: Use an environment variable: [Ktor docs](https://ktor.io/docs/configurations.html#environment-variables)

Comment: @Gabriel Pizarro
Thx. So... Environment variables are not accessible by visitors making reverse engineering?

Comment: Values for environment variables are usually stored in files that are accessible only for users who have access to the server.